# ProtectedConfigurationProvider.Decrypt keep fired when decrypt config section node

Tags: c#, config

I'm trying to protect config file of .Net desktop app with [ProtectedConfigurationProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.protectedconfigurationprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) according to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b(v=vs.80).aspx). I implement a new provider class, to protect config section, I deserialize section node to model, encrypt string value inside, then serialize encrypted model to section node and put into a new "EncryptedData" element, vice versa.
For example, I have a "appSettings" section in config file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="test key" value="test value" />
</appSettings>
```

after encrypted:

```
<appSettings configProtectionProvider="customProtectionProvider">
  <EncryptedData>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="6ZefRBry+Q" value="6ZefRB2w7OuU" />
    </appSettings>
  </EncryptedData>
</appSettings>
```

Here is the problem I have: When I try to decrypt the protected config data, Decrypt method in my custom provider will always be fired when I deserialize encrypted section xml to model, and then get into deserialize part again.

1. load configuration and get "appSettings" section

   ```
   Configuration config = 
       ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
   ConfigurationSection appSettingsSection = 
       config.GetSection("appSettings"); // fire Decrypt method here
       // ......
   ```
2. in Decrypt method of provider

   `var sectionModel = ConfigurationBase.Deserialize(encryptedNode);`
3. Deserialize

   ```
   //...get custom section type by encryptedNode.Name
   Type sectionType = typeof(Section.AppSettingsSection);
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(sectionType); // fire Decrypt method here and then infinite loops
   ```

here is my AppSettingsSection class:

```
[XmlRoot("appSettings")]
public class AppSettingsSection : ConfigurationBase
{
    [XmlAttribute("file")]
    public string File { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("add")]
    public List<KeyValueNode> Settings { get; set; }

    protected override void encryp()
    {
        // ......
    }

    protected override void decrypt()
    {
        // ......
    }
}
```

I don't know why create XmlSerializer with this type will call Decrypt method of ProtectedConfigurationProvider.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: It's so weird... When I build the project in vs2010, not vs2012 like before,  everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded debug symbols of System.Xml.Serialization and step into it, then I found after 65 lines of [TempAssembly](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/Compilation.cs,62dd5af1452c3c04) class, `ProtectedConfigurationProvider.Decrypt` method will be called, so I checked out [TempAssembly.UseLegacySerializerGeneration](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization/Compilation.cs,566b39e85f253ba8,references) property, in getter it called `System.Xml.Serialization.AppSettings` class which trying to get value from `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` config section, but I have enctypted it before, so `Decrypt` method is called again.

Finally the solution is avoiding encrypting `appSettings` cofnig section.